# How to make an HTML div occupy the rest of the available height

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application where I want the content to fill the height of the entire screen. How to make the `div` (`other-child`) fills its parent automatically without doing calculation on its height.

```css
html {
height:100%;
}

body{
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

#parent {
height:100%;
}

#child {
height:50px;
background:yellow;
}

#other-child{
background:red;
/* height: 100% */
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" >fixed height</div>
    <div id="other-child">occupy the rest</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css grid on `#parent` and control everything from there, and it will be as simple as this :

```css
html {
height:100%;
}

body{
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

#parent {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr
}

#child {

background:yellow;
}

#other-child{
background:red;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" >fixed height</div>
    <div id="other-child">occupy the rest</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this solution, parent will be `display:flex` and the child which will grow can be done using `flex-grow: 1`

```css
html {
height:100%;
}

body{
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

#parent {
height:100%;
width:100%;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-direction: column;
}

#child {
height:50px;
background:yellow;
}

#other-child{
background:red;
flex-grow: 1;
/* height: 100% */
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" >fixed height</div>
    <div id="other-child">occupy the rest</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: red;
}

#other-child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child" >fixed height</div>
    <div id="other-child">occupy the rest</div>
  </div>
```